# how to post data to a site database in an iphone application?

Tags: iphone, database

I want to create an iphone application that is able to post the data to a website database which is using MySQL. Can anyone give some hints?

Comment: You probably want to create a REST API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557040/objective-c-best-way-to-access-rest-api-on-your-iphone

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use NSURLConnection and NSURLRequest to send the data to the server.