# Using a REST API and iPhone/Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rest, netflix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C: Best way to access REST API on your iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557040/objective-c-best-way-to-access-rest-api-on-your-iphone)

So I'm brand new to Netflix's API and have never used an API ever before. I'm ok with Objective-C and Cocoa Touch but just have no clue where to start when accessing the API and how to in general. Can someone help me get started with some code that will access titles in Netflix or just how to access a REST API in general with authentication. Thanks.

Update: I've looked at the documents and I'm still a little lost because the Netflix API is a little weird with OAuth. Any help?

Comment: Same question , look at [Objective-C: Best way to access REST API on your iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557040/objective-c-best-way-to-access-rest-api-on-your-iphone)