# Rails and iOS app, authentication question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, devise, restful-authentication, restkit

I want to build web service in Rails 3 and iOS app to work with this service.
I need simple thing. User when first time open iOS app, get login screen. When is logged in, iOS app can send and get requests.

I already used Devise for authentication on Rails, and found RESTKit for iOS to map objects and use RESTfull web services, bit I didn't found anything about to confirm to work together.

My question is, **what is the best solution to use on both sides**, iOS and RoR **to make this to work**?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want to use RestKit, what is stopping? They will work great. You just have to map your objects to your rails app responses. Devise the right option as well.

Comment: I didn't try RestKit with Device, and I want to be sure that there is no some unusual problems in that combination :)

Comment: RestKit is great! Using it already :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP authentication between devise and iphone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474532/http-authentication-between-devise-and-iphone-app)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [what I did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474532/http-authenticaiton-between-devise-and-iphone-app/6483222#6483222) for the same setup (IOS device <=> Rails webservice).