# Can anyone provide sample code for Reskit 0.20 authentication and Rails?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, restkit

Can anyone help with Reskit 0.20 authentication and Rails? I can't find anything on this.

Comment: Did you check out this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474532/http-authentication-between-devise-and-iphone-app/6483222#6483222