# objective-c Best API for restful web service

Tags: iphone, objective-c

what is the more simple way to use RESTful web service who return JSON in iphone app ?

thanx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Best way to access REST API on your iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557040/objective-c-best-way-to-access-rest-api-on-your-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

http://restkit.org/ is a nice API for that on iPhone, http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ + a JSON parser ( https://github.com/stig/json-framework for example) should also do the job !

You should also find some other options here : [Objective-C: Best way to access REST API on your iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557040/objective-c-best-way-to-access-rest-api-on-your-iphone)