# REST webservice integration for iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services

I am creating an application in which i have to fetch data from web service of REST type and now i am not getting suitable way to work with REST web service. In my application there should be the get and post commant works for the web service. can anyone help me to integrate REST web service for iphone application in Objective c.
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

http://restkit.org/ is a nice API for that on iPhone, http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ + a JSON parser ( https://github.com/stig/json-framework for example) should also do the job !

You should also find some other options here : Objective-C: [Best way to access REST API on your iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557040/objective-c-best-way-to-access-rest-api-on-your-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use this project from github - https://github.com/akosma/iphonerestwrapper
This project have some great classes to work with REST on iPhone